# How to explain the results from different block sizes?

Tags: cache

I vary the D-cache block size for a program. I test different block sizes for the D-cache, block sizes from 1 to 8. Size = 128 words, and blocks in sets (associativity) = 1.

```
Block size     1     2     4     8
Access time   30    20    15    12
Hit rate      1%    50%   75%   87%
Cycle count 34921 24241 18901 15769
```

Please help me explain the measurement values for hit rate and cycle count. Why does the hit rate suddently improve so much as a increase the block sizes?

Comment: This is pretty much a near duplicate of the earlier questions. You're best off studying this stuff in some good textbook. Some authors that come to mind are: Hennessy and Patterson; William Stallings.

Comment: Hennesy and Patterson's *Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach* goes into numbers on this type of stuff, as the title promises.

Comment: @Kaz Thank you for the comments and for the references .I own the Hennesay book which I'm studying but I learn much more from direct interaction with my exact questions than sitting for months digging through the same old text. I need to understand concrete examples and I have just a few questions only about caches and about interrupt handlers, I seem to understand everything in the Hennessay Computer Organization and Design except for the cache memory part and the part about interrupt handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are these homework questions of some sort?

The hit rate goes up with block size because the first miss in a block essentially "prefetches" the rest of the block, and as long as the other items in the block get used before it is replaced (very common with sequential accesses for both instructions and data), they are automatic "hits" in the cache.

The cycle count goes down because a cache miss takes more cycles than a cache hit.

Comment: Yes, I've had trouble learning caches as I'm studying the Hennesay / Patterson's book studying for computer engineering exam and going through notes. I can understand all the course material except a) cache memories and b) interrupt handlers (that must be written in assembly). We used the Nios 2 FPGA (Altera DE2) for the laboratory exercises and the university is www.kth.se